# How to add value and get decimal number result instead of ASCII symbols

Tags: assembly, type-conversion, numbers, x86-16, emu8086

I'm new to assembly code and I'm trying to create a program to add 2 two digit values from user. But the result is ASCII symbol, what can I do to display the decimal number?

```
.model small 
.stack 100h
.data
digit1 db "enter first digit: $"
    digit2 db 10,13,"enter 2nd digit: $"
number1 db 0
number2 db 0
first_number db 0
second_number db 0
result db 0
result_digit1 db 0
result_digit2 db 0

.code
main proc
;Prompt the user to enter the first number
    mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

lea dx, digit1
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

; Read the first digit of the first number into AL
mov ah, 01h`your text`
int 21h
sub al, 30h     ; convert the ASCII code to its corresponding number
mov [number1], al

; Read the second digit of the first number into AL
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h     ; convert the ASCII code to its corresponding number
mov [number2], al

; Combine the digits to form the first number
mov al, [number1]
mov ah, [number2]
mov bx, 10
mul bx
add al, ah
mov [first_number], al

; Prompt the user to enter the second number
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset digit2
int 21h

; Read the first digit of the second number into AL
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h     ; convert the ASCII code to its corresponding number
mov [number1], al

; Read the second digit of the second number into AL
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h     ; convert the ASCII code to its corresponding number
mov [number2], al

; Combine the digits to form the second number
mov al, [number1]
mov ah, [number2]
mov bx, 10
mul bx
add al, ah
mov [second_number], al

; Add the two numbers
mov al, [first_number]
add al, [second_number]
mov [result], al

; Convert the result to ASCII code
add al, 30h
mov [result_digit1], al
mov al, [result]
div bx
mov [result_digit2], al
add al, 30h

; Print the result
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, [result_digit2]
int 21h
mov dl, [result_digit1]
int 21h


Main endp
End main
```

For example, the result i expect when entering 11 + 22 the result would be 33 but the answer I got is ASCII symbol instead of integer. How can i get integer numbers instead of ASCII symbol

Comment: You want `digit1 * 10 + digit2`, not `((digit1<<8)|digit2) * 10` with that `mul bx`, and then you add the high and low halves of the low 16 bits of the product.  Check the manual for how `mul` works, and don't load `number2` into a register until you've already multiplied the most-significant digit.

Answer (score 0):

### Check your input first

With `mul bx`, you are performing the **word-sized** multiplication that multiplies AX by BX. You need to use the **byte-sized** multiplication for multiplying the most significant digit by 10, and then adding the least significant digit to it:

```
mov  al, 10
mul  number1
add  al, number2
mov  [first_number], al
```

Same for *second_number*.

### How to output results up to 99

> the result i expect when entering 11 + 22 the result would be 33 but the answer I got is ASCII symbol instead of integer.

Your conversion code is adding the 30h value too soon!
The first step needs to be decomposing the value in *result* using the **byte-sized** division by 10:

```
mov  al, [result]   ; [0,99]
cbw                 ; Will perform AX / BL
mov  bl, 10
div  bl             ; -> AL is tens, AH is ones
```

The next step converts these digits into text characters:

```
add  ax, '00'   ; Same as `add ax, 3030h`
```

The last step prints the digits:

```
mov  dx, ax     ; -> DL is tens
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
mov  dl, dh     ; -> DL is ones
int  21h
```